# Generating markdown documentation for VBA code

Tags: python, python-3.x, vba, markdown

## Generating documentation for VBA code

The goal of this exercise to is create an application which can read module files created in VBA project and generate markdown documentation for them.

### Key features

- User should be able to pass **standard module (bas)** based on which markdown file is created.

### Limitations

- There are more more types than just **standard module (bas)** in VBA project. For now, they are not supported.
- Entry point of application (`main`) is yet not defined.

### Project structure

```
vba-doc-py
│   module_parser.py
│   module_parser_tests.py
│   method_parser.py
│   method_parser_tests.py
│   module_doc.py
│   module_doc_tests.py
```

### Code

**module_parser.py**

```py
import module_doc


class ModuleParser():
    """This parser is responsible for extracting information from raw VBA code
    which later, can be used for generating markdown document."""

    def make(self, code):
        lines = code.split('\n')

        for ln in lines:
            if 'Attribute VB_Name' in ln:
                dbl_qut = ln.index('\"') + 1
                name = ln[dbl_qut: ln.rindex('\"')]
                doc = module_doc.ModuleDoc(name)

            elif 'Public Sub' in ln or 'Public Function' in ln:
                doc.addMethod(self.__get_method_name(ln), self.__get_args(ln))

        return doc.build()

    def __get_method_name(self, ln):
        method_type = 'Sub' if ' Sub ' in ln else 'Function'
        name_start = len(f'Public {method_type} ')
        open_parenthesis = ln.index('(')
        return ln[name_start:open_parenthesis]

    def __get_args(self, ln):
        open_parentheses = ln.index('(')
        close_parentheses = ln.rindex(')')

        if self.__no_args(open_parentheses, close_parentheses):
            return ''

        # Remove surrounding parentheses
        args = ln[open_parentheses + 1: close_parentheses]

        args_list = args.split(', ')
        output = []

        AS_KEYWORD = ' As '
        for item in args_list:
            as_keyword_start = item.index(AS_KEYWORD)
            arg_type = item[as_keyword_start + len(AS_KEYWORD):]
            output.append(arg_type)

        return output

    def __no_args(self, open_parentheses, close_parentheses):
        return open_parentheses + 1 == close_parentheses

    def __remove(self, text, start_index, count):
        """Returns a new string in which a specified number of characters in the current 
        instance beginning at a specified position have been deleted."""

        return text[:start_index] + text[start_index + count:]
```

**method_parser.py**

````py
class MethodParser():
    """Class responsible for parsing VBA methods (both Sub and Function)
    and turning them into specified markdown format."""

    def make(self, code):
        return f'# {self.__get_method_name(code)}\n\n```vb\n{code}\n```'

    def __get_method_name(self, ln):
        method_type = 'Sub' if ' Sub ' in ln else 'Function'
        name_start = len(f'Public {method_type} ')
        open_parentheses = ln.index('(')
        return ln[name_start:open_parentheses]
````

**module_doc.py**

```py
class ModuleDoc():
    """Represents markdown document on the module level."""

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.subs = {}

    def addMethod(self, name, args):
        self.subs.update({name: args})

    def build(self):
        output = '# ' + self.name + ' module\n\n'
        if len(self.subs) > 0:
            output += ('# Methods\n\n'
                       '|Name|Description|\n'
                       '|-|-|\n')

            for name in self.subs:
                output += f'|[{name} ({self.__format_args(self.subs[name])})](./{name}.md)||\n'

        return output

    def __format_args(self, args):
        if isinstance(args, list):
            return ', '.join(args)
        else:
            return args
```

### Conclusion

I'm working mainly with C#/VBA and that is mostly a style which I apply here, because it is the style which I know best. Also I'm aware that Python most definitely have it's own **style** which I'm looking forward to explore.